# Reload scripts after page transition (Highway JS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, transition

I'm trying to implement page transitions on my website. Right now, i've chosen to use "[HighwayJS](https://highway.js.org/)" (I am also using Webpack).

My issue is that when my new page loads, the scripts and styles aren't reloaded. I've looked at the docs of Highway and i [found this](https://highway.js.org/examples/managing-scripts-styles.html) : some functions to reload the scripts and styles. But i can't figure out how to implement those 2 functions in my project...

Right now, i have 2 pages (let's say Home and About). Each page have common files as well as specific javascript files (with webpack, i've created chunks "`chunks: ['commons', 'vendors', 'app', pathname],`"), same for css (each page have a common css file as well as a specific one).

I've implemented a simple Fade transition. Here is what my app.js file looks like

```js
import './scss/main.scss';

import $ from 'jquery';
import { TimelineMax, TweenMax, Power4, Power3, Power2, Power1 } from 'gsap/TweenMax';
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';

import './components/shared/cursor';
import './components/shared/menu';
import './components/shared/loadingScreen';
import Fade from './components/shared/fade';

import homeRenderer from './components/renderers/home';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

const H = new Highway.Core({
  transitions: {
    default: Fade
  }
});

// H.on('NAVIGATE_END', ({ location }) => {});
```

1. How do i add a particular ID to my script tag in webpack so i can
   implement it? (the first line of these functions being `const main =
   document.querySelector('#main-script');` i understand that i have to add an id to my main script. What if i'm using multiple scripts like vendors, main, etc. ?)
2. How can i implement these 2 scripts? Meaning where am i supposed to put it? (do i create a `H.on('NAVIGATE_END', ({ location }) => {});` and put the 2 functions inside?)